# reading different Excel sheets in Python with if-elif-else

Tags: python

I am trying to read different sheets from Excel with if-elif-else statement depending upon the input and have written following code

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd

def ABSMATDATA(a,b,c,d,Material,Tmpref):
    if Material == 2.016:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='H2')
    elif Material == 28.016:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='N2')
    elif Material == 32.000:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='O2')
    elif Material == 32.065:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='S')
    elif Material == 18.016:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='H2O')
    elif Material == 64.065:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='SO2')
    elif Material == 12.001:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='C Graphite')
    elif Material == 28.011:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='CO')
    elif Material == 44.011:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='CO2')
    elif Material == 16.043:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='CH4')
    elif Material == 30.070:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='C2H6')
    elif Material == 44.097:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='C3H8')
    elif Material == 58.124:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name='C4H10')
    else:
        print('No data for this material available')
        df =[list(np.arange(0,1100,100)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1))]
    return df
```

I am trying to run the Code calling `ABSMATDATA(1,2,3,4,28.011,100)` in the IPython Console but it is not giving any output. I was expecting to see the `df` in my Variable Explorer as an 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Do you have a return statement at the end of the function definition?  Otherwise it is just reading in the excel spreadsheet and doing nothing with it.

Comment: double check the sheet name too

Comment: I do have return statement immediately in the next line after df=[list(np..........] statement

Comment: sheetnames are all correct, checked it multiple times till now

Comment: Add your return and correct your indentation then

Comment: Code edited with return, but still no df in my variable explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not `return`ing anything, and you can *cut* your code a bit:

```
def ABSMATDATA(a,b,c,d,Material,Tmpref):
    material_map = {2.016: 'H2',
                    28.016: 'N2',
                    32.000: 'O2',
                    32.065: 'S',
                    18.016: 'H20'}

    if Material in material_map:
        df = pd.read_excel('F:\MAschinenbau\Bachelorarbeit\ABSMAT.xlsx',sheet_name=material_map[Material])
    else:
        df = [list(np.arange(0,1100,100)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1)),list(np.arange(0,11,1))]
        print('No data for this material available')
    return df
```

Comment: still no df in my variable explorer

Comment: @Pradeep You need to assign function call to variable

Comment: sorry, I dont understand what you mean by assigning function call, could you please explain or give an example ?

Comment: @Pradeep for example use `a = ABSMATDATA(1,2,3,4,28.011,100)` and you'll see `a` in variable explorer

Comment: thanks I did the way you said and I can see the data in the variable explorer. But I don't understand the logic behind it, I have already a variable "df" where the data from the excel should be stored then why do I again need to define a variable in Console ?

Comment: @Pradeep Thanks for accepting. The variable `df` is within function `ABSMATDATA` scope and cannot be accessed out of it, making it invisible to variable explorer. Read more about scopes [here](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html)